# Case Statement Multiple Then values

Tags: sql, case

Not sure if this makes sense, I am trying to edit an Existing sproc to add a variable to the "Where" clause to either Return all of the Value, None of the Value, or every record regardless of the Value.

I am using a Case When/ Then statement in the Where clause.

```
  WHERE 
      CASE (@work)
  WHEN 'Y' THEN part.corpid = ( 'Work EMP' , 'Work EMP 10' , 'Work FAM' )
  WHEN 'N' THEN part.corpid != ( 'Work EMP' , 'Work EMP 10' , 'Work FAM' )   
  ELSE part.corpid = *
  END
```

The setup is if its Y, then return only employee's and their families, if N then do no return any employee or their Family, and if NULL in the variable, then return everything.

I have no idea what I am screwing up here, I keep getting errors on the = in the Y Section.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
(
  @work = 'Y'
  AND part.corpid IN ( 'Work EMP' , 'Work EMP 10' , 'Work FAM' )
)
OR
(
  @work = 'N'
  AND part.corpid NOT IN ( 'Work EMP' , 'Work EMP 10' , 'Work FAM' )
) 
OR
(
  @work is null 
  -- add other filters here if needed
  -- no need to include the part.corpid because all will be included
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had it all hammered out, but clearly I did not.

Comment: @dj18 It probably could.  Does it need to be a `CASE` statement?  Sometimes a `WHERE` clause is much easier.

Comment: @bluefeet - I was wondering what the problem is with the OP's code that your code corrects: is it the usage of `CASE`, or the `=` instead of `IN`?

Comment: @dj18 OP is trying to compare multiple values in the `CASE` that is part of the problem. If one value was being returned it would be much easier to use `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle example:

```
CASE grade 
  WHEN 'A' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
  WHEN 'B' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Very Good');
  WHEN 'C' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Good');
  WHEN 'D' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Fair');
  WHEN 'F' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Poor');
  ELSE dbms_output.put_line('No such grade');
END CASE;
```